# Spring Data CrudRepository on java based configuration - EntityManager - no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-data, entitymanager

I've read I believe tried all of the posts on this, but no luck in finding the right answer. 
I am using java based configuration with my spring mvc project, and wanted to try Spring CrudRepository, to get away from DAOs, and that is when the whole hell broke loose:
started with "no transaction is in progress" on flush after persist:
- tried adding @Transactional to the method - none of the variations found here worked
- tried changing configuration, but since it is java based, most of the answers are xml based. no luck either.
So finally I have to ask:

How to configure my project to make CrudRepository persist, or how to create Spring EntityManager using java configuration.

This is the last version of my configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "ba.fit.vms" })
@ImportResource(value = "classpath:spring-security-context.xml")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/persistence.properties"));
        return ppc;
    }


    // Security Configuration
    @Bean
    public KorisnickiServis korisnickiServis(){
        return new KorisnickiServis();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        return new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember-me-key", korisnickiServis());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // Jpa Configuration
    @Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${dataSource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${dataSource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${dataSource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbm2ddlAuto;   

    @Bean
    public DataSource configureDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("ba.fit.vms");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);
        //jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(configureEntityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

I've tried number of variations, but was always receiving same "no transaction is in progress" error.
Also, just a glimpse at the repos:
LokacijaRepository:

```
@Transactional
public interface LokacijaRepository extends CrudRepository<Lokacija, Long> {

}
```

And LokacijaRepositoryImpl:

```
@Repository
public class LokacijaRepositoryImpl implements LokacijaRepository {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("repo");
    @PersistenceContext // tried this as well(type= PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @Override
    @Transactional// tried number of variations here as well, like REQUIRED...
    public <S extends Lokacija> S save(S entity) {
        logger.debug("trying to save!");
        try {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            entityManager.flush();
            return entity;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("error: "+ e.toString());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

If you need anything else to help me figure this one out, let me know.

Comment: If you are using Spring Data JPA (which seems to be the case), why do you have `LokacijaRepositoryImpl`?

Comment: I guess I though it's a must? How do I do it?

Comment: I cannot believe!!! I removed LokacijaRepositoryImpl and got this error: "No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined". I looked at the documentation and it says use default name: 'entityManagerFactory'. I changed the name of the method from configureEntityManagerFactory to entityManagerFactory and that was it!!!

Comment: That's good to know! Do you think you or I should add it as answer? Do you think it will help future readers?

Comment: It would not hurt to have it answered. There is not enough information on anotation based configuration so it should be recognized. Put the answer here and I will mark it as answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to create an implementation of `LokacijaRepository` (in `LokacijaRepositoryImpl`) while Spring Data JPA (which you have configured) is trying to do the same.

What you need to do is:

1. totally remove `LokacijaRepositoryImpl`
2. Either change `configureEntityManagerFactory` to `entityManagerFactory`  **or**  add `entityManagerFactoryRef=configureEntityManagerFactory` to `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Removed the implementation of repository, and renamed the configureEntityManagerFactory to entityManagerFactory, and it worked like a charm! I have not tested adding it, but I might later on.